# PWM a heatgun using a relay

Tags: ac, pwm, heat

I need to control a heatgun temperature. My heatgun have two different temperatures, one about 300° and another about 400°/500°(something like that) with 2kW max power at 220v. I've connected a temperature sensor at hotgun output, and now I want to try to PWM a relay that is connected between heatgun and AC. Relay take about 4/5ms to change between ON/OFF.

My question is: What I can damage if I PWM a heatgun?

Of course relay will not survive many years, but it's cheap to replace. Can I damage home electrical system(lifeguard electrical system if name is correct)? or can I damage heatgun becouse maybe fan run slower and resistor overheat?

Comment: With PWM cycles about 10s and max pause of 0.5s and min. on time 0.5s, it will survive quite a long time.

Comment: as @MarkoBuršič suggests, you don't need a fast PWM for a heat-gun, and if you use a relay you will be switching asynchronously to the AC - that's not good if the load is inductive (a heat-gun will be slightly) - you may get arcing on the relay contacts when it turns off. Can you use a solid state relay - which will switch synchronously?

Comment: You should put the relay in series with only the heater element and leave the fan running as normal. That way you will get full fan speed regardless of the PWM.

Comment: Consider using a solid state relay, you can switch it quite fast.

Comment: I haven't done this, but I think this will work fine. If you do not need precise control, you can use simple hysteretic switching. In other words, if temperature is 5 degrees below target, turn on heating element. If temperature is 5 degrees above target, turn off heating element. Otherwise, make no change. As others suggested, adding a minimum on and off time of 0.5 seconds would also be good, and use a relay to switch heating element only. Since this is kind of heavy use, maybe use a relay rated for more than 2kW. Hopefully that will extend its life.

Comment: Why not just a common triac dimmer/motor-control module/circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Your home electrical system will not be damaged by this, but you might get interference on a TV or radio as the relay switches. As suggested, you don't need to PWM very frequently -- every few seconds should be OK.

What are you trying to regulate ? What regulates the PWM on-time ?

Instead of a relay, you could use a triac (like in a light dimmer), although finding a 2 kW one might be difficult. A triad only switches off at the zero crossings of the AC signal, and will therefore generate less interference than a relay.